# Step Over not working in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

In the function below, let's say EIP is 0x400688. Now, I want to step over the call instead of stepping inside the subroutine.

```
    0x40067a <main+4>       sub    $0x20,%rsp                                                                                                         │
   │0x40067e <main+8>       mov    $0x3c00,%edi                                                                                                       │
   │0x400683 <main+13>      mov    $0x0,%eax                                                                                                          │
  >│0x400688 <main+18>      callq  0x400560 <alarm@plt>                                                                                               │
   │0x40068d <main+23>      mov    0x2009ac(%rip),%rax        # 0x601040 <stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5>                                                        │
   │0x400694 <main+30>      mov    $0x0,%ecx                                                                                                          │
   │0x400699 <main+35>      mov    $0x2,%edx                                                                                                          │
   │0x40069e <main+40>      mov    $0x0,%esi
```

I used the next command however it starts executing the main() function itself instead of just executing call and breaking at instruction: 0x40068d as shown below:

```
(gdb) next 
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between nexti and stepi in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024529/whats-the-difference-between-nexti-and-stepi-in-gdb)

Answer (score 1):

`next` will not work as intended unless there is source line information in the symbol table.

From [Next: Skipping Over Functions and Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html):

> Continue to the next source line in the current (innermost) stack
>   frame. This is similar to step, but function calls that appear within
>   the line of code are executed without stopping. Execution stops when
>   control reaches a different line of code at the original stack level
>   that was executing when you gave the next command. This command is
>   abbreviated n.
>
> An argument count is a repeat count, as for step.
>
> The next command only stops at the first instruction of a source line.
>   This prevents multiple stops that could otherwise occur in switch
>   statements, for loops, etc.

Comment: Then what is the alternative? How do I step over the function call?

Comment: @NeonFlash I typically set a breakpoint at the memory address of the instruction immediately following the function call. Then when I get to the function call I `continue` to skip the function code.

Comment: Yes, that is one way but I was expecting a more convenient way instead of setting a breakpoint each time there is a call instruction.

Answer (score 1):

As said, `next` won't work if the source has not its symbol table. You can obtain such debug symbols with `-g` option from gcc.

But otherwise, I think you're looking for the command `nexti` that can be shortened to `ni`.